# Plot 2 boxplots , each from different pandas dataframe in a figure?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, boxplot

I want to plot boxplots for each of the dataframes side by side. Below is an example dataset.

data 1 :

### id |type |activity | feature1

1 | A | ACTIVE | 12

2 | B | INACTIVE| 10

3 | C | ACTIVE| 9

data 2:

id | type | activity | feature1

1 | A | ACTIVE | 13

2 | B | INACTIVE | 14

3 | C | ACTIVE | 15

First boxplot should be to plot the feature1 grouped by type and the second boxplot should be to plot the feature1 grouped by activity.Both the plots should be placed in the same figure.
Note : I do not want to do combined grouping.

Comment: I tried with the layout argument ,. But that did not work out.

Answer (score 0):

Use `return_type='axes'` to get `data1.boxplot` to return a `matplotlib` Axes object. Then pass that axes to the second call to `boxplot` using `ax=ax`. This will cause both boxplots to be drawn on the same axes.

Alternatively if you just want them plotted side to side use matplotlib `subplot`

Comment: I know about this solution. But is there a way to get this as a seperate chart ?

Comment: have you considered using subplots?